# Basic C - Switch cases duplication

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, scanf, whitespace

I am working on a project, where you answer a char, and if it is not one of the 4 answers, it tells you to try again. If it is not the correct one of the 4, it stops running. Here is a snippit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool switchCheck = true;
char answer;

        printf("A. English\nB. French\nC. Spanish\nD. German\n");
      do{
        scanf("%c\n", &answer);
        switch (answer){
          case 'C':
            printf("Very nice ");
            break;
          case 'B':
          case 'A':
          case 'D':
            printf("Sorry! Incorrect. Code Ends\n");
            switchCheck =false;
            break;
          default:
            printf("Try Again\n");
        }
      }while(switchCheck==true);
```

For some reason, when I input A, B, or D, it first prints the result for default, and if I do it again immediately afterward, it gives me the right input. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: May we please see the other code that surrounds this?  (A "minimal reproducible example" as it were.)

Comment: It's almost certainly due to the way you are reading the input. Which you have not shown. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: `case '\n': continue;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using scanf like

```
scanf("%c\n", &answer);
```

Instead use

```
scanf( " %c", &answer );
```

See the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`. It allows to skip white spaces.